# Does Elastic search have an incorrect usage of RAM?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does Elastic search have an incorrect usage of RAM?

I found a few problems with ES that make it not an option for a large dataset:

- Maximum capacity to run per machine 32BG; you can run several instances, but you will start degrading the performance of ES.
- 32GB might be ok, but the recommendation is to cache the File system to 32GB or more. But how do we know what data is in ES and what is on the filesystem? Is there any duplication of data? Is there any control or optimisation on what data is on ES or the Filesystem?

What I see is a lack of control over the RAM usage. This problem occurs when your data is larger than several 100s of GB.

How can we optimize ES with the filesystem to avoid data redundancy and use the RAM correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> But how do we know what data is in ES and what is on the filesystem?

The rule of thumb for elasticsearch is that if something can be read directly from disk - it is not cached in elasticsearch, elasticsearch assumes that it will be cached in the file system cache. If something needs to be read from disk and then certain operation on such data needs to be performed (for example, queries or aggregations results) and there is a high chance that such data will be reused, it is cached in the elasticsearch.

> Is there any duplication of data?

There is no direct duplication, but some elasticsearch caches might contain the results of the operations performed on data stored in the file system cache.

> Is there any control or optimisation on what data is on ES or the Filesystem?

There are different types of data stored in both places. So while you cannot choose what type of data stored where, you have some control over internal cache sizes and [pre-loading data into file system cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/preload-data-to-file-system-cache.html).

> How can we optimize ES with the filesystem to avoid data redundancy and use the RAM correctly?

I think you might find this [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-caching-deep-dive-boosting-query-speed-one-cache-at-a-time) useful.